# Bitshifting elements in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, bit-shift

I have an assignment in which I must read a list of 4000 names from a text file and sort then into a C style array as they're being read in (rather than reading them all then sorting). Since this is going involve a lot elements changing indices would it be possible to use bitshifting to rearrange large quantities of elements simultaneously?For example,

1. declare a heap based array of 20 size
2. place variable x index 10
3. perform a bitshift on index 9 with the size of the array data type so that x is now in index 11

Also, if you have any tips on the task in general I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Tip: Write some code. If you have a specific problem/question, come back, post the code and ask again.

Comment: Using array will require a lot of shifting, is linked list not an option for you? Also I don't get what you mean by 'using bitshifting'.. in what way?

Comment: It's an assignment with two elements, one being a linked list and the other must be a C style heap based array. 

I'm basically trying to come up with an efficient way of moving say 100 elements in an array to the right by one element so that I can place something in the previously occupied element at the start in an efficient way.

Comment: You should use a `std::list`.  These are great for inserting, and sorting in your scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that doesn't sound at all like something you'd use bitshifting for.

You will have distinct elements (the names) stored in an array, and you need to change the order of entire elements. This is not what bitshifting is used for; it is used to move the bits in a single integer to the left or to the right.

You should just learn `qsort()`.

Not sure about the "sort as they're being read in" requirement, but the easiest solution would be to just call `qsort()` as each name is added. If that's not allowed or deemed too expensive, think about how to do a "sorted insert" against an array.

By the way, a typical approach in C would be to work with an array of pointers to strings, rather than an array of actual strings. This is good, since sorting an array of pointers is much easier.

So you would have:

```
char *names[4000];
```

instead of

```
char names[4000][64 /* or whatever */];
```

This would require you to dynamically allocate space for each name as it's loaded though, which isn't to hard. Especially not if you have `strdup()`. :)

Comment: It was a long shot, I'll just have to resort to using the expensive methods. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

If using qsort() is not allowed(would be pretty stupid to do so after every insert), you could write your own insertion sort. It's not exactly a very efficient way of sorting large arrays but I suppose it's what your teacher is expecting for.